# Understanding the proof of "Every integer greater than $1$ has a prime divisor"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The proof is by contradiction, starting by stating that some integer $n\gt 1$, "has no prime divisor. By the well-ordering property, we may assume that
$n$ is the least such integer. Now $n|n$; since $n$ has no prime divisor, $n$ is not prime. So $n$ is composite and consequently there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=ab$, $1<a<n$, and $1<b<n$. Since $1<a<n$, we have that $a$ has a prime divisor, say $p$, so that $p|a$. But $a|n$ so we have that $p|n$ by Proposition 1.1 (which states if $a|b$ and $b|c$, then $a|c$) from which $n$ has a prime divisor, a contradiction. So every integer greater
than $1$ has a prime divisor." (End proof)

I am having trouble understanding the last line "$n$ has no prime divisor, $n$ is not prime. So $n$ is composite". I understand it's the purpose of the proof, but how does $n$ not having a prime divisor mean it must be composite?

Using this example: "If $B$ is prime, its divisors/factors are $1$ and $B$. Since $B$ is prime, it has a prime divisor $B$". So then, am I supposed to assume I don't know about prime factorization for the purpose of this proof and this is why $n$ must be composite?

Comment: I view it more simply: $B$ or have divisors different from $1, B$, or have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original proof you provided, the assumption is that n has no prime divisor. Based on this assumption, the proof demonstrates that n cannot be a prime number because a prime number, by definition, must have at least two distinct positive divisors (1 and itself), and since n has no prime divisor, it cannot satisfy this condition. Therefore, the conclusion is that n must be composite.

```
Two distinct divisors that are talked about and seems you are confused with are : 

 - 1 (Not a prime divisor)
 - n itself (It is also not a prime divisor due to our assumption that number n doesn't have any prime divisor)
```

> I understand it's the purpose of the proof, but how does n not having a prime divisor mean it must be composite?

If n has no prime divisor, it means there is no prime number that can divide n exactly. If n were a prime number, by definition, it would have exactly two distinct positive divisors: 1 and n itself. But since n has no prime divisor, it cannot have these two distinct divisors, contradicting the definition of a prime number. Therefore, if n has no prime divisor, it cannot be a prime number, and the only alternative is that n must be composite.

> So then, am I supposed to assume I don't know about prime factorization for the purpose of this proof

So, if you are working on the proof without assuming prior knowledge of prime factorization, the proof still holds, as it relies on the basic definitions and properties of prime and composite numbers.

In summary, the last line of the proof is stating that if an integer n has no prime divisor, it cannot be a prime number and must be composite and why it is to be composite is stated above.

If it isn't clear still, feel free to ask!

Comment: My post does not have the full proof, so if you'd like me to add that in I will do so. Aside from this, I now understand better the elimination of n being a prime thus only leaving composite as a choice. But then I thought of how not every composite number fulfills the requirement of not having a prime divisor (semiprimes for example). But I think for this proof I should try to ignore as much of my prior knowledge as possible, since, as you said, it's not assumed I should know them. Thank you!

Comment: Thinking again, even with the knowledge of semiprimes, by taking the condition that it doesn't have a prime divisor, it "takes away" the prime divisor leaving only 1 and itself thus making it a prime meaning it explicitly has a prime divisor so it can't fulfill the requirement of n not having a prime divisor. Like 34 for example, take away (2,17) you're left with (1,34) in the eyes of the condition; but with 36, take away its prime factors and their respective partners, you're left with (1,36), (4,9) and (6,6), so it does "fulfill" the condition. That is, assuming my thinking is correct.

Comment: You are correct, and I apologize for the confusion caused. If we assume that n has no prime divisor, it does not necessarily mean that n must be composite. In fact, as you said, there are composite numbers such as semiprimes that have prime divisors. To be very true, I must say that this point mistakenly slipped out of my mind. As of now the proof statement feels incorrect, however it would be great if you attach the full proof so we can look into it once.

Comment: Your explanation was still helpful as it allowed me to understand the assumption better than I did before, which was only barely. I added in the full proof for you to see.

Comment: Who says 36 fulfill the condition? We may further factorize 36 i.e. into prime factors......The number 36 is a composite number with prime factorization 2^2 * 3^2. This means that its prime factors are 2 and 3.
If we remove the prime factors 2 and 3 from 36, we are left with 1 and 1, which are not equal to the original number itself. Therefore, 36 does fulfill the condition of having no prime divisor, as it has been reduced to 1 (which is not considered a prime number) after removing its prime factors.

Comment: I must apologize to you that I feel that the confusion is entirely caused by me who is having a really hard time in writing english...lol Some words may get here and there...I hope you understand....Anyways still trying my best

Comment: I was assuming that prime factorization is not known for the proof, so 6=2*3 is not known. But I am still learning to understand proofs so it's possible this assumptions is not correct. And I would say your english is great so don't worry about it, haha.

Comment: Assumption seems pretty solid though. The fact is that I being a mediocre high schooler can't provide more reasoning.....I must say for upcoming answers, that will be better for sure, this lad stands in the same queue as OP for a firm explanation. This transition from answering to looking for an ans was smooth, lol. You were really kind btw.

Comment: Not to make this terribly longer, but this is often goes in learning in these types of areas. The more you learn the more knowledge/ideas you get so you ask more questions to get more exact answers. So essentially, let us keep learning